# WebServices Security

Tags: appsec, attacks, penetration-test, web-service

Do we have any good resources on WebServices Security? Any book, pdfs, articles and even the detail answers regarding the securing web services would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to know what technology you are aiming for. WebServices is really broad and are written in many different languages.

Comment: Karrax is right.  There are hundreds of questions here with the tags you've used.  Also search for "blog", "education" etc. on the site.

Comment: @nealmcb,Karrax: Before posting the question, I tried to search all those mentioned tags but couldn't find anything here and I know its a very broad topic so before starting I just wanted to know few basics you know few pointers with which I can proceed with. Thanks for the comments though. I will look into the OWASP WebServices page as mentioned by Mike. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_The_Open_Web_Application_Security_Project) (The Open Web Application Security Project) provides a lot of resources for developers and pen-testers.

> OWASP is an open community dedicated to enabling organizations to conceive, develop, acquire, operate, and maintain applications that can be trusted. All of the OWASP tools, documents, forums, and chapters are free and open to anyone interested in improving application security.

To the degree that web applications qualify as web services, are accompanied by web service APIs, or can be hardened/probed using the same techniques as web services, OWASP is a great resource.

You might start at their [Web Services](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Services) page.

Comment: Thanks Mike. OWASP just got slipped from my mind. Thanks.